# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'util'

Tags: reactjs, node-modules, saas

My React app was working fine until today, when I run npm start the following error is displayed

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'util' in 'C:\Users\Lui\Desktop\React\BarPoint\node_modules\sass'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "util": require.resolve("util/") }'
- install 'util'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "util": false }
```

I have tried to delete the node modules and  did `npm i`but still error is persisted,how do i resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by adding the following code im my webpack.config file

```
fallback: { 
    util: require.resolve("util")
  },
```

then i did `npm i util`
There was also an error about fs,,,After a lot of research i solved that by adding this code in the package.json in sass folder under node modules

```
"browser": {
    "fs": false
},
```

i also added the same code in my normal package.json

Answer (score 2):

To solve this issue I did this following steps:-

```
1) delete package-lock.json file
2) delete node-modules if required
3) delete dist folder if exists.
4) npm install
```

Everything should work now, it was the package-lock.json that blocked npm to download old versions of dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem, webpack.config.js should look like this

```
module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(js)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: [
                ['@babel/preset-env', { targets: "defaults" }]
              ]
          
           
          
            },
```

then npm i util after that npm start.